# Can we add multiple marker using geo uri scheme

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, cordova

I want to add multiple marker on a button click event !!i am using phonegap with angularjs. What exactly should happen is when i click the button google maps application should open up and multiple markes should be displayed deppending on number of location... I have been succeeded in adding single marker using geo uri..

```
<a  class="button-green button-green--large" ng-href="geo:{{selectedClass.latitude}},{{selectedClass.longitude}}?q={{selectedClass.latitude}},{{selectedClass.longitude}}">Locate</a>
```

p.s. I have searched stackoverflow previous questions and found that i will be able to complete the above task by adding static map , but i wish to open the google map on button click event, which i wont be able to using aforesaid method.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can set multiple markers on google maps anymore. Instead, you can make an activity, or a web service to handle it, just like this one:

IMG: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=235x227&maptype=roadmap&markers=37.970982,23.724559|37.971487,23.724953|37.973291,23.726862

URL: http://kylelam.github.io/SO/customMarkers.html?size=235x227&maptype=roadmap&markers=37.970982,23.724559|37.971487,23.724953|37.973291,23.726862

[image]

Comment: but i wont be able to navigate or use other google map functions if i use the above link .. Right?

Comment: it depends on how you implement your version of "Google Maps", using the google maps api. But, yea, it is not maps.google.com.

Comment: Umm !!Any tutorial or link about how to implement my version of google map. I dont know how to start about this thing. Heard about this for the first time. And yeah thamks fr your time

Comment: oh.. I meant, you can add your search bar back to the page. and other options. but it is still not google map...